# Indacene pericyclic mechanism question

Tags: organic-chemistry, reaction-mechanism

[image]

I am looking for any help in developing a mechanism for this transformation as well as determining the stereochemistry on the starred centers. I do not see any obvious connections. I was thinking that the second to last step would involve some sort of electrocyclic ring closure since the hydrogen atom orientation is a consideration for the product. Beyond this, I can't justify any further reactivity. There is no acid to lead to carbocation-mediated ring closure. I can't see any obvious sigmatropic rearrangements nor cycloadditions that would either directly or indirectly lead to this.

I had already taken the suggestion of rotating the single bond into consideration. Can someone please confer with me on the stereochemistry, though? Kindly see below.

[image]

Comment: Rotate the central single bond and see if there's no "obvious sigmatropic rearrangements nor cycloadditions" ;)

Comment: What you have proposed is a 4n (n=4) thermal, conrotatory electrocyclization where the hydrogens at the newly-formed sigma bond will be trans disposed. Some double bonds in the final two structures are missing or misplaced.

Comment: @user55119 - this is how it was listed in the source - since there are an even number of electron pairs (6), would this not following thermal/even/conrotatory Woodward-Hoffman rules? The double bond may be obscured by the orbitals in the drawings; that is a software issue and I apologize! Do you agree or disagree with trans disposition?

Comment: Yes, the hydrogens will be trans as predicted bt W-H rules. http://ursula.chem.yale.edu/~chem220/chem220js/STUDYAIDS/pericyclic/pericyclic.htm#Electrocyclic